# Updating OKTA’s user profile from Angular application

Tags: angular, okta

My question may be basic but I have trouble finding a way to update user profile from my own angular UI.

I didn’t think a basic user operation like this is that much complicated but it seems it is.

I followed the instruction to update my user, using okta user API:

https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-oauth-for-okta/overview/

And then I tried to apply the same concept in my angular project which I managed to use Okta angular widget and I can register user and login from my app.

this is my configuration:

```
oidc: {
clientId: ‘jkefkjefkjdfkjfkgfkgj’,
issuer: ‘https://udhfjkhdfhejfhdjfh.okta.com/oauth2/default’,
redirectUri: ‘http://localhost:8080/login/callback’,
scopes: [‘openid’, ‘profile’, ‘email’, ‘okta.users.manage.self’],
testing: {
disableHttpsCheck: false
}
}
```

With this scope ‘okta.users.manage.self’, it gives me an error like this:
error.errorCode: invalid_scope, error.description: One or more scopes are not configured for the authorization server resource.

After some research, I found just "Org Authorization Server" can mint tokens for accessing OKTA API, which is in this address:

> 'https://udhfjkhdfhejfhdjfh.okta.com/oauth2'

But when I use this I get the following error:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://udhfjkhdfhejfhdjfh.com/oauth2/api/v1/authn' from origin
> 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The 'http://localhost:8080' is in the Trusted Origin and it works fine with the default Custom Authorization Server.

Is there any way to do a simple mundane job with OKTA which include:

1. Register User. It is already done
2. Login with that user. It is already done
3. Update User profile. I am struggling to make it.

Comment: I don't think Okta's APIs allow you to do this from a SPA. You have to have a backend that can communicate with its APIs using a client secret. For example, you could use the Java SDK to update a user's profile. See example at https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/01/23/replace-local-storage-with-okta-profile-attributes.

Comment: It is what I thought. But I was wondering if I can register a user using Okta Angular widget, why I cannot update that user in the same fashion.

Comment: It might be possible in the future. But it's not now AFAIK.